# How to convert String to Date and set default timezone in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

I use node.js and have below requirement.
There is a date format string 1899-12-29 12:00 AM, now i want to convert it to Date object, i try to use moment.js or moment-timezone.js to convert it, while it will set the timezone to my local timezone(see the below code)

```
var dateTimeStr1 = '1899-12-29 12:00 AM';
var d = moment(dateTimeStr1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A').toDate()
```

In my date string, there is no timezone information, i want to convert it to date and set the timezone to UTC +0, so the date object value looks like that
`1899-12-29 12:00 AM UTC +00:00`

How can i implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `moment.utc(dateString, dateFormat)`

```js
var dateTimeStr1 = '1899-12-29 12:00 AM';
var d = moment.utc(dateTimeStr1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A').toDate()
console.log(d)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```